# Javascript background color blink with fade

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div that needs to have a constant flashing background color.

All I want it to do is fade in from **transparent** to **red** and back in a loop.  I've seen a few *examples* that do this, but they all affect the entire contents of the `div` rather than just the `background color`.

Other examples have a flashing `background` but it's not a smooth transition, which is what I need.

I'd rather not use *CSS* animations if possible.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `needs to have a constant flashing background` Ugh.

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a DYI site... Searching google will certainly bring up dozens of tutorials.

Comment: It's not meant to be obnoxious, I need a gradual fade. It's for a small div on a chart that appears when a certain threshold has been met on some data

Comment: I've searched and read about all the tutorials relevant to this and can't find an example that does exactly this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `rgba` color to fade the color to transparent.

Example:

```
var ofs = 0;
var el = document.getElementById('imp');

window.setInterval(function(){
  el.style.background = 'rgba(255,0,0,'+Math.abs(Math.sin(ofs))+')';
  ofs += 0.01;
}, 10);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/BUL2z/

Using jQuery:

```
var ofs = 0;

window.setInterval(function(){
  $('#imp').css('background', 'rgba(255,0,0,'+Math.abs(Math.sin(ofs))+')');
  ofs += 0.01;
}, 10);
```