# How to blink the background of specified cell or row in Vaadin FilterTreeTable?

Tags: css, background, vaadin

I'm using Vaadin Tepi Filter Tree table to display trade portfolio record and want to blink the background of specified cell when data changed.

I can update the User Interface by using PUSH method in vaadin, but don't know how to blink the background color, please help.

Comment: If you want to make it [blink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809616/javascript-background-color-blink-with-fade) you may need some [javascript](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.javascript.html) integrated into your Vaadin app. If you only need to have a different background colour, you can use a [simple cell style generator](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.table.html#components.table.css).

Answer (score 2):

You can basically achieve this by using CSS animations and the Vaadin [addStyleName()](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Component.html) function. When you want to blink your data, just add some style to the element that should blink. See the sample below on how to implement a background change with CSS animations.

```css
    .blink {
      animation: blink 1s steps(5, start) 3;
      -webkit-animation: blink 1s steps(5, start) 3;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
    }
    @keyframes blink {
      to {
        background-color: green;
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes blink {
      to {
        background-color: blue;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="blink">&nbsp;</div>
```